# ggplot2: How can I add a symbol in ylab(expression(paste())) after a subscript

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new in the world of ggplot2 but with your help I already got far. However, now I am struggling with a "simple" thing. The title of my axis is supposed to look like "Fs/Fo,  Fm/Fo" (the small letters "s","o" and"m" subscripted. therefore I use:

+ylab(expression(paste(F[s]/F[o]~~~~~~~F[m]/F[o])))

Like this the letter are subscripted, but I am not able to get a comma right behind the Fo. It either gives me an error:" **Error: unexpected ',' in..** "or, if I put it in "", it just appears as:"F[s]/F[o],~~~~~F[m]/F[o]"  Does anyone have any solution for this small issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)), aes(x,y))  +
   geom_point() + 
   ylab(expression(paste(F[s]/F[o]~","~F[m]/F[o])))
```

[image]